# Set the application icon in .net core 1.0 WEB API Projects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Recently I've developed in Visual Studio an ASP.NET Web Application based on .net core 1.0 and .net Framework 4.5.1

This application produces a .exe file, my main issue is that I've not been able to find anywhere where to change the icon of the compiled executable in the Project

In a normal Windows application the icon can be easily set in Visual Studio right-clicking on the main project, then go in "Properties" where you can specify the icon and also the manifest

I've seen that in the "project.json" file is possible to specify "IconUrl" inside the "packOptions" section but this seems to work only when the target is a NuGet package and not an exe like my case

Any Suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: ...since when do web applications generate an exe? It's supposed to generate a dll that you can then load into the Kestral or IIS app servers.

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem to be implemented at the moment. There is an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3267) regarding this at the dotnet/cli GitHub repository, with Milestone set as **Backlog**.